Help with understanding Ricci flow for non-trivially induced metrics
I'm trying to do some self-education on Ricci flow. I'm a little confused on what exactly the equation
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} g_{ij} = -2 R_{ij}
$$
is saying for Riemannian metrics g. In the case of the round sphere, one can take the metric
$$
g = \left[ \begin{matrix}
r(t) & 0 \\
0 & r(t) \ sin(\theta)  \\
\end{matrix} \right]
$$
and show that since $R_{ij} = \frac{g_{ij}}{r^2}$, factoring out the $r^2$ from each component of $g$, one has a straight forward ODE to solve for r(t). The solution shows that the sphere parametrically shrinks or grows in radii and there's a "flow" so to speak in this sense.
In the case of the 2-sphere, the "induced metric" is pretty trivial since for $r = const. \ $ the spherical metric $ds^2 = dr^2 + r^2 (d \theta ^2 + sin^2 (\theta) \ d \phi^2 ) \ $ is simply a constant multiple of $ \ d \theta ^2 + sin^2 (\theta) \ d \phi^2 \ $ and one doesn't have to worry about the differential on $r$. Our "flow" is pretty nice and easy to work out.
My question is what about non-trivially induced metrics? How do I find their ricci flow?
Take the equation $r = a + b*cos(\theta) + c*sin(\theta)$ for constants $a, \ b, \ \text{and}, \ c \ $. Here, $ \ a \ $ and $ \ b \ $ parameterize an indent that goes to a singularity at the north and south poles. How can I get a picture of what the ricci flow here looks like? I'd like to be able to take $ \ a \ $ and $ \ b \ $ and make them my parameter I differentiate with respect to, taking the place of $ \ t \ $ in the ricci flow equation, but obviously these derivatives don't yield the correct components of the ricci tensor. If this is an incorrect approach to parameterizing my metric, I can't see why. I don't believe the ricci flow can be the same as the round sphere either. Certain values of $ \ a \ \text{and} \ b \ $ cause sections of the surface to reach the origin (or wherever the surface is centered around) before the other portions for a parametrically shrinking radius.
Perhaps the equation I cited as the ricci flow equation isn't suitable for the surface I chose as an example.
Edit: I may have overcomplicated conveying my question. Simply put, for the surface $r = 1 + a*sin(\theta)$, the induced metric is $[(a*cos(\theta))^2 + (1+a*sin(\theta))^2] \ d \theta^2 + [sin^2 (\theta) * (1+a*sin(\theta))^2] \ d \phi^2$. Here, $ \ a \ $ controls the indentation that happens at the boundaries of $\theta$ parametrically, giving the family of surfaces. But $ \ \frac{d}{da} g_{ij} \ $ is clearly not the correct ricci tensor. Solving for $ \ g_{ij} \ $ by setting its derivative w.r.t some parameter equal to the ricci tensor of the desired metric, the metric that gives the ricci tensor doesn't fall out. What am I not understanding here?

I'm not sure I entirely understand your question. The Ricci flow is a differential equation for $g_t$, and $g_0$ must be given. What would $g_0$ be in your second example? If it is given by $r(0)= a+b\cos(\theta)+ c\sin(\theta)$, then a parameter $t$ will show up. On the other hand, if, say, our parameter is $b$, then $r(0)=a+c\sin(\theta)$, and we'll see what $r(b)$ looks like once we solve the Ricci flow $$\frac{\partial}{\partial b} (g_b){ij} = -2 (R){ij}$$

@Dog_69 so I need to specify an initial condition for anything to work here? is it true that so long as I specify the curvature explicitly that I should get the corresponding metric, just with a non trivial t-dependence?

@DinfleGlop The existence and uniqueness theorem stated in Wikipedia (see here) requires an initial metric tensor $g_0$, yes. Regarding your second question, the Ricci flow is a Partial Differential Equation. I'm not sure specifying the Ricci tensor Will be enough, as it might not be a solution for the equation. Hope any of this is helpful
